# How to add form values of a component which are created using dynamic component loader?

Tags: typescript, angular

I have a component which loads using DCL. I want to add the control group to parent form.I have made a [plunker demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/hOqzUkrYOIyWYkploJ4q?p=preview) . I dont know how to bind the child control group to parent.

```
add() {
    this._dcl.loadIntoLocation(DynamicCmp, this._e, 'location').then((ref) => {
      ref.instance._ref = ref;
      ref.instance._idx = this.idx++;
      this._children.push(ref);
    });
}
```

And this is how i am adding components.Somebody please tell me how to add the child controls to the control in parent form

Comment: I'm also curious to know the answer. Been trying since you posted here. But nothing is working out.

Comment: @micronyks Thank you for your spending your valuable time.Here is the updated plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/hOqzUkrYOIyWYkploJ4q?p=preview. I got the values of child form added to parent using the ref when component is created.Now i am trying to destroy the control from parent when individual or all the components are disposed

Comment: Oh great answer. Yes remove method removes it. but doesn't remove it from completeForm.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that you can pass anything to DLC component or vice versa. What you can do, and i think it is handier solution to use:

```
 this.completeForm.addControl("sku", new Control)
```

Look at Plunker:
http://plnkr.co/edit/MahOzQqkyv613N1NtElF?p=preview